# Programatically check which versions of .NET Compact Framework are installed

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a Windows Mobile application that is built for .NET CF 1.0. It is written in C#. How can this program check what versions of the .NET Compact Framework are installed on the device it is running on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by "installed".  If they were installed via CAB file (the most common), there will be entries in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETCompactFramework` that you could programmatically check.

Comment: It can be added as part of the OS, which I think might add the same registry entry (I've never checked) and the CF files can actually be deployed individually with the app, where no registry entries would exist.

Comment: I tried to look in the registry of a device via Start > Run... > "regedit" but it told me it had never heard of such a beast (in so many words)

Comment: CE devices don't ship with regedit, unless the OEM added one, and I've never seen one on a handheld.  Use the Remote Registry Editor tool (or download a CE registry editor like PHM's).